# Ionic 2 customize back button action

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I want to customize the click-action of the back button mentioned in this screen capture. I want that by clicking I do not return to the previous page but to a page that I specify myself, or do a treatment before going back.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: what kind of customize you want. i think ionic provides by default this icon on child pages

Comment: I want that by clicking I do not return to the previous page but to a page that I specify myself, or do a treatment before doing back.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For customize default back button action you need override the **backButtonClick()** method of the NavBar component.

**Step 1:** In your **"custom-class.ts"**  import Navbar component. Create auxMethod for override the default behavior and called in your ionViewDidLoad method.

```
import { Navbar } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class myCustomClass {
    @ViewChild(Navbar) navBar: Navbar;

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.setBackButtonAction()
    }

    //Method to override the default back button action
    setBackButtonAction(){
       this.navBar.backButtonClick = () => {
       //Write here wherever you wanna do
          this.navCtrl.pop()
       }
    }
}
```

**This code has been tested in ionic 3.**

Comment: @theHellyar You have to import NavBar and create the variable with the "navBar" name.

Comment: @ArielAntonioFundora turns out it was a view child of a component so I had to reference the view child of the component...so basically a view child of a view child... thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`ionViewCanLeave` or `ionViewWillLeave`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/) event.

See this [issue #9533](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/9533) with proposal to distinguish leave events for "back" navigation. This can be handy for your use case once implemented.

Answer (score 0):

***You need to just remove the current index from stack of ViewController***

import { ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';

```
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
      }


this.navCtrl.push("APage").then(() => {
      const index = this.viewCtrl.index;
      this.navCtrl.remove(index,1);
    });
```