# Force Ionic 2 Navbar to use setRoot() instead of pop()

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

When navigating to a different page, `ion-navbar` places a back button to `pop()` to the previous page. Is there a way to change this behaviour so it uses `setRoot()` instead of `pop()`, or will I have to use `ion-toolbar` instead and manually add my own custom back button?

(As a side note, the reason I want to use `setRoot()` is because it's an easy way to force the previous page to refresh instead of using the cached version. Using lifecycle hooks like `ionViewWillEnter` don't seem to get around this problem. So if there's another way around this all together, I can try that as well.)

Comment: you want to maintain the state ?

Comment: @Aravind I want it to refresh the previous page when tapping the back button, not use the cached version. `setRoot(previousPageName)` achieves this, but `ion-navbar` uses  `pop(previousPageName)` by default.

Comment: You can use **hideBackButton** class in ion-navbar    <ion-navbar hideBackButton>.And then manually add custom back button.

Comment: @Math10 Thanks. Anyway to make it use the "Back" text as well? I'm not sure how to use `setBackButtonText()` in this context. I know I can just add "Back" inbetween the `<button>` tags, but the formatting is messed up doing this.

Comment: Check my answer to related question where you can change the default behavior of back button.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019241/ionic-2-customize-back-button-action/45361158#45361158)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `setRoot()` then you won't have any back button.If you need to add it, you can just do that manually.

e.g. of `setRoot()`

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(EventSchedulePage);
```

About the Lifecycle hooks, you can use `ionViewDidEnter`.It runs when the page has fully entered and is now the active page. This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached page.

You can refer [**it here**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/).see it under the `Lifecycle Events` caption.